# Cannot set property '0' of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a JavaScript code that applies properties from an object to a HTML element's style, but there's something wrong in the code. I know I can do it the other ways, but this is what I'm trying to do.

```js
var elem = {background:"red",
            position:"fixed", 
            height:"25px",
            width:"100px"
           }; 

var htmlObj = document.querySelector(".element");
var x; 

var cssProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elem);

for(x in cssProperties){
  htmlObj.style.cssProperties[x] = elem[cssProperties[x]];
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

I am getting the below error:

[image: error message: uncaught type error]

What am I missing?

Comment: Typo. There's no `cssProperties` property of the `style` object. The `background` at all are properties of `style` itself. You must have copy/pasted it by error.

Comment: Try:  htmlObj.style[cssProperties[x]] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have few fixes you need to do:**

---

**First**, `for .. in` statement iterates over `enumerable properties`, while `cssProperties` is an array (`iterable object`), which means you should use `for ... of` statement instead.

`for(x in cssProperties)` will result `x` to be `0, 1, 2, ...` etc...
and `for(x of cssProperties)` will result `x` to be the values of elements in the array `cssProperties`.

---

**The second thing** that should be fixed is the access to the style property. by writing `htmlObj.style.cssProperties[x]`, you are trying to access the property named `cssProperties` inside `style` which is not exists. You want to set the property `cssProperties[x]` of `styles`.

So you should write:
`htmlObj.style[cssProperties[x]]`

In fact, `x` is already the property name you want, so it should be: `htmlObj.style[x]`.

---

**Finally**, you want to access the value of `x` in `elem`, so instead of `elem[cssProperties[x]]`, use `elem[x]`.

---

### Final code should be:

```js
var elem = {background:"red",
            position:"fixed", 
            height:"25px",
            width:"100px"
           }; 

var htmlObj = document.querySelector(".element");
var x; 

var cssProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elem);

for(x of cssProperties){
  htmlObj.style[x] = elem[x];
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

By the way. you have some extra steps over there. You can us `for .. in` straight on `elem` as the object, without extracting its properties and iterate over them. So a cleaner code would be:

```js
var elem = {background:"red",
            position:"fixed", 
            height:"25px",
            width:"100px"
           }; 

var htmlObj = document.querySelector(".element");

for(let x in elem){
  htmlObj.style[x] = elem[x];
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :) Happy coding! 
I've added another cleaner approach